# Browser compatibility with Firefox 41

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When i initialize a variable(backbone.js model) with new keyword, its working in all latest browsers(chrome and firefox).
But the same is not working in Firefox41

```
    var backboneModel = new BackboneModel();
```

and the error in the console(only firefox41) is

```
TypeError: BackboneModel is not a constructor
```

any clues?

**Update**

I have success call back which is causing the issue.
the following error came after new Blob statement

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

at

```
   success: function(model, response){
                     // Create a new Blob object using the 
                     //response data of the onload object
                     var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'text/csv'});
                     //Create a link element, hide it, direct 
                     //it towards the blob, and then 'click' it programatically
                     let a = document.createElement("a");
                     a.style = "display: none";
                     document.body.appendChild(a);
                     //Create a DOMString representing the blob 
                     //and point the link element towards it
                     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                     a.href = url;
                     a.download = 'Sample_Report.csv';
                     //programatically click the link to trigger the download
                     a.click();
                     //release the reference to the file by revoking the Object URL
                     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
```

Comment: [`let` is a ES6 feature](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) which was implemented in Firefox 44.

Comment: thanks for the tip Emile

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a `.` in `var backboneModel = new Backbone.Model()`